# Oracle Database Regex For Repeating Group of Characters

Tags: regex, oracle

I think my question is quite straightforward. Examples for my case are:

```
ababababab
acacacacac
adadadadad
...
azazazazaz
```

I need a regex that can detect all the cases I mentioned above.

I have tried using:

`(a\w){5}`

But it doesn't work as it also passes:

```
abacadaeaf
```

Thank's for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use backreferences, which are supported by Oracle regular expressions:

```
(a\w)\1{4}
```

`\n` refers to the *n*<sup>th</sup> capture group (as counted by opening parentheses).

Comment: You might find this helpful. http://www.regexper.com/ for when you can't get your regex to work, or when you want to prove it does. Just copy the expression in and it will give you a graphical representation of it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : `(a\w)\1+` This will match all the references of the character group occured after "a".

and `\1` This backreference will do the trick.

If you want to match exact 5 groups of charcter 'ab' or 'ac' or ... then use this regex : `(a\w)\1{4}`