# Oracle Database Regex For Repeating 2 Group of Repeating Characters

Tags: regex, oracle

I would like to know how to write a single regex in Oracle that can detect the following expressions:

```
aaaaabbb
aaaaaccc
aaaaaddd
...
aaaaazzz
```

I have tried:

```
a{5}\w{3}
```

and

```
a{5}[a-z]{3}
```

and

```
a{5}(\w)\1{2}
```

but if failed as it also detects `aaaaadef`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The regex `a{5}(\d)\1{2}` shouldn't work because it matches strings like `aaaaa111`. `\d` matches numbers only. This said, `a{5}(\w)\1{2}` should reject `aaaaadef` and work as intended... [See here](http://www.regex101.com/r/dE1oW3)

Comment: Your last regex — `a{5}(\w)\1{2}` — appears to be intact.

Comment: Also, related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16807275/1578604 @rofansmanao Please accept one answer by clicking the 'tick' button (found under the vote count of an answer) when you are satisfied with it for each of your questions.

Comment: I don't know if any answer really solves this, the regex seems to comply with the oracle flavor of regex, and it is correctly constructed to match the listed examples.

Comment: You need the backreferences, but for me `a{5}(\w)\1{2}` doesn't detect `aaaaadef`; it seems ok. `^a{5}((?!a)[\w])\1{2}?$` also works if you don't want `a` in the second group, and want to match the entire string.

Comment: And if you can't use the lookaheads and don't want `a` in section 2 of the string, then see my answer for use of `[b-zB-Z0-9]` instead

Comment: Sorry everyone, I was having problem with browser at office pc today and I couldn't response to comments or answer.. Thank you for all the feedback...

Answer (score 1):

To further extend [Felipe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813212/458741) about not needing regular expressions there's no need for *anything* complicated at all here. If I steal his table creation script, the following would work:

```
SQL> select *
  2    from t1
  3   where replace(substr(field1, 1, 5), 'a') is null
  4     and substr(field1,6,1) = substr(field1,7,1)
  5     and substr(field1,6,1) = substr(field1,8,1);

FIELD1
---------------------------------------------------------------

aaaaabbb
aaaaaccc
aaaaaddd
aaaaafff
```

If you wanted to make it slightly neater you could use [`REGEXP_COUNT()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions147.htm#SQLRF20014) but I don't see how it makes much difference:

```
SQL> select *
  2    from t1
  3   where regexp_count(substr(field1, 1, 5), 'a') = 5
  4     and regexp_count(substr(field1,6), substr(field1,6,1)) = 3;

FIELD1
----------------------------------------------------------------------

aaaaabbb
aaaaaccc
aaaaaddd
aaaaafff
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93bb4/1) to demonstrate.

Comment: Nice. But how to know where the text you are trying to match starts? I assumed the text was "mixed" inside a sentece or something (for example, the string "this is a text and aaaaabbb"), that's why @rofansmanao asked for a regular expression. But if that's not the case your answer is much better indeed.

Comment: That's entirely possible @Felipe... I've answered the question as is... :-).

Comment: I loved the SQLFiddle link =)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>What is it you are trying to match out of that?</strike> 
**edit** I think I now understand what you are looking for, so have adjusted the below regex

You are going to need something like [oracle's backreferences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm)

```
^a{5}((?!a)\w)\1{2}?$ // will match aaaaaddd but not bbbbbddd - this is probably what you need
```

**edit 2** If you are doing this in the database instead of in java accessing the database, then you may have to drop out the lookahead `(?!a)` in the above as it might not be supported in the db. Other alternatives (with lookaheads removed) are:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9])\1+([a-zA-Z0-9])\2+?$ // will match aaaaaddd, aaaadd, bbbbdd, aaaaaaaa
^([a-zA-Z0-9])\1+([b-zB-Z0-9])\2+?$ // will match aaaaaddd but not aaaaaaaa
^([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{4}([b-zB-Z0-9])\2{2}?$ // will match aaaaaddd but not aaaaadd
^a{5}([b-zB-Z0-9])\1{2}?$ // will match aaaaaddd but not bbbbbddd
```

This will find an alphanumeric, with another one of the same alphanumeric next to it, n times, and then another group. This is going to be the basis of what you need. Note `\w` is not necessarily the same as `a-zA-Z0-9`, but `[b-zB-Z0-9]` might be the best you can do if you don't want `a` in the second group.

**edit** added `^` and `$` to force an entire string match, based on the comments added, and added options based on the possible requirements

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9])\1+` would be wrong here, he just wants to match 5 `a` followed by 3 `a-z`, but the 3 last ones should be identical. As far as I can understand from the question

Comment: @melwil. I've forced an entire string match, which should take care of your comment. I think we might need a negative lookbehind though to force the second group to be different to the first - it's hard to know if that's a requirement though.

Comment: You missed the point here, your regex will match any number of the first letter, and it will also match `bbbbbvvv`, the question is clearly stating he wants to only match `a`.

Comment: @melwil. I had originally assumed the first repeating character could be any letter, and repetitions (it was just two repeating groups), have adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I wouldn't do a regex at all.
If the comparisons you are trying to make are as simple as your example, I would do a simple like instead.
I assume you are trying to do these comparisons in a SELECT statement?

```
 create table t1 (field1 varchar2(100));

 -- what you want
 insert into t1 values ('aaaaabbb');
 insert into t1 values ('aaaaaccc');
 insert into t1 values ('aaaaaddd');
 insert into t1 values ('aaaaafff');

 -- what you dont want
 insert into t1 values ('aaaaaabc');
 insert into t1 values ('aaaaadef');
 insert into t1 values ('aaaaafgj');

 -- Just do a simple like
 with regex 
 as
 (-- all the possibilities
  select 'aaaaa' || rpad(alphabet, 3 , alphabet) lookup
  from  (-- a through z
         select chr(96 + rownum) alphabet
         from   dba_objects
         where  rownum <= 26) 
  ) 
 select *
 from   t1
 where  exists (select *
                from regex
                where t1.field1 like '%' || regex.lookup || '%')
```

I did an EXISTS instead of a join in case a line in your tables matches more than one regex.lookup.
Just an idea though.

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as (
select 'aaaaabbb' as val from dual
union
select 'aaaaaccc' as val from dual
union
select 'aaaaadef' as val from dual
union
select 'aaaaa___' as val from dual
)
select *
from x
where regexp_like(x.val, 'a{5}([a-z])\1{2}')
```

output:

```
aaaaabbb
aaaaaccc
```

Note that 'a{5}(\w)\1{2}' does NOT work since (\w) will match alphanumerics and underscore, and from your examples you want a-z only.